# Application of Dependency Inversion Principle with ASP.NET Provider Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, dependency-injection

I have an application which uses an `IPaymentService` to process credit card payments. The appropriate implementation (`CreditCardPaymentComponent` or `CheckPaymentComponent` or anything else that implements the `IPaymentService` interface) is injected into the application by a `PaymentProvider` using the [ASP.NET Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479030.aspx).

We also need these components to be reusable for different applications which may not have access to the `PaymentProvider`.

The question is where to put the `IPaymentService` interface? It can't be inside the application because there are multiple applications which need to use the service. It can't be inside the service because there are multiple services which implement this interface. I don't like putting the interfaces in their own project because then I have to add references everywhere. Is there another solution?[image: Provider Model]

**EDIT:** To clarify, the point of using the Provider Model is so we can support other developers, so they can write for example `CustomPaymentComponent` which implements `IPaymentService` and it works seamlessly with our app. I am leaning towards @Frazell's answer but I am just wondering if there is any downside to putting `IPaymentService` in the same assembly with the `PaymentComponent`s? If you had to develop a `CustomPaymentComponent` for this system, what would make the most sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't escape having to have the interface and the implementation code referenced where it is needed. If the payment code has to be reusable in many applications I would break it out into a separate library (dll) and package it appropriately.

Managing the additional assembly is a lot easier than resorting to code duplication, which is the only alternative. Duplication has to be avoided at all costs.

Depending on what you're doing overall. I would provide the interface and base implementations in the same assembly (such as a payments assembly) and allow use of DI to swap out the implementations where needed in edge case scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is actually quite simple:

> **Use the adapter pattern.**

You don't let the components implement that interface at all, but implement adapters for each component based on that interface. In that case the adapter and interface can be placed together:

```cs
class CreditCardPaymentServiceAdapter : IPaymentService 
{
   private CreditCardPaymentService service;

    public CreditCardPaymentServiceAdapter(
        CreditCardPaymentService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // Implement IPaymentService here and forward
    // to the CreditCardPaymentService.
}
```

This adapter itself will contain no business logic, but will just map/transform/adapt to the real `CreditCardPaymentService` and exposed the `IPaymentService` (or which interface is suited for that application).

If you have multiple applications, you might be forced to duplicate these adapters and the interface. That's the downside.

Comment: the diagram is a simplification; i actually have 25-30 different PaymentComponents so I don't think adapter is an option

Comment: In that case  either use dynamic or place the interface in a shared assembly.